# Set Max Age for GAE Datastore Entries

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm writing a program using Java Google App Engine. I'd like to have certain types of entities automatically removed from a datastore once they reach a certain age, to prevent using unnecessary memory. Here's the very unexciting way I'm creating entities:

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Entity entity = new Entity("thingamabob","special_thingamabob");
    datastore.put(entity);
```

In this case, I'd want to have special_thingamabob automatically go away from the datastore after, say, 12 hours. I know I could give each entity a timestamp and then use cron to query every hour for timed-out entities, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Make a task timed to execute in X hours that deletes the model at the same time you create it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [background-threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Background_threads) might work:

```
    Thread thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
 private volatile boolean isRunning = true;
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (isRunning) {
        Thread.sleep(12*60*60); // sleep for 12 hours
        datastore.delete(key); //then delete key
        isRunning=false;
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted in loop:", ex);
    }
  }
});
thread.start();
```

Comment: It seems that Timer is not allowed on GAE.

Comment: that will cost a lot of instance time for no reason... why not the Push/Pull task queues?  or a cron scheduled job to check the whole datastore and delete "old" entities?